# Change calendar language in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

My Calendar's days are in spanish, as well as the month names. I want to change it to english. How can I do this?

I am running xubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into Language settings --> Regional Formats, and set to English.

[image]